# Which Ports are used by Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, port, azure-service-fabric

I was running a Service Fabric Application on Port 9008 quite some time now.
Now, I wanted to have an new application running on Port 5000. However, I was not able to connect to the app on the remote secure cluster, but on my local cluster.

However, after I changed the port to 9009 and changed the Load Balancer's Health Probe and the Load Balancing Rule to do it's magic on port 9009 instead of 5000, everything just worked.

Is there a list of Ports you may not use for your own Service Fabric Applications?

Comment: When you setup a cluster, you specify the Application Port Range, please check the docs on the section Setup your cluster and specify your resources in a manifest file. From there you will understand how SF map the ports to your application

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But my question rather is about how can I review the settings, i.e. I did not create the cluster myself. Also, there are quite some "pre-allocated" ports which are used by the platform itself.

Comment: You can get the information about the ports by querying for the cluster manifest (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/servicefabric/vlatest/get-servicefabricclustermanifest). There are C# and REST APIs as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brent did an amazing job creating a secure template for Service Fabric. It contains all the information about what ports are in use and why.

You can find the blog post here:

- https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/08/01/network-isolationsecurity-with-azure-service-fabric/